# Select features from different vector layers at once?

Tags: qgis, point, select

I have two vector files in the layers panel in QGIS (V2.8.2, Wien).

I am trying to select points from both vector files simultaneously to view in both attribute tables - both tables are set to show selected features only.

The only way I can do this is to select one layer in the Layers Panel, then select features by rectangle, then select the second layer in the Layers Panel and reselect again using the rectangle.

Is there a way to select features from both layers and only using select by rectangle once?

Comment: With relations?

Comment: Have you found a way to accomplish this using QGIS 3.4.4-Madeira?

Answer (score 13):

To select from all layers at once, you need to install [Multiple Layer Selection](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/MultipleLayerSelection/) plugin from

`Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins -> search for "Multiple Layer Selection"`

The Multiple Layer Selection plugin has two options:

1. Multiple Selection by point, and
2. Multiple Selection by Rectangle

[image]

Use option 2 to select the point and the polygon from multiple layers as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: This plugin does not seem to be available for QGIS 3.4.4-Madeira

Comment: @kalakaru Not all plugins are updated to QGIS 3 and this plugin is one of them.

Comment: Have you found another way to accomplish this using QGIS 3.4.4-Madeira?

Comment: @kalakaru No. As this is a custom behavior of QGIS, only through programming you can achieve this.

Comment: The plugin is now available for more recent versions of QGIS 3. I'm using it in v3.14

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with QGIS 3.16 "Merge vector layers"

Answer (score 7):

I recently developped a [small plugin for QGIS3](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/multilayerselect) that adds a toolbar with a "multilayer" version of the QGIS selection tools. You can also optionaly replace the default tools with the custom ones.

[image: toolbar]

**Note**: While I was developing it, the original plugin was ported to QGIS3. I encourage you to give both a try :)

Comment: Just used it, very useful plugin, thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach doesn't require any additional plugins at all.

Simply use **Vector -> Research tools -> Select by location**
Next, you can modify the current selection by adding a new selection within just the selected polygon.

[image]

The biggest advantage of this method is, that you can use selected features from your polygon layer, which predominantly have irregular shapes.
All the plugins proposed above won't be as much help as they could be. The first one allows you to make multiple selections just within the box. The second one requires a manual drawing of the selection area.
I think sticking to the Select by location method is the most convenient option.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is now available for more recent versions of QGIS 3. I downloaded it today in QGIS v3.14.

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/MultipleLayerSelection/

or in QGIS go to 'plugins' > 'manage and install plugins' > search for 'multiple layer selections' plugin.

Comment: It's installed. Now what? Can you include instructions? Particularly since there are no instructions on the linked page.

Comment: @JoshM. there should now be a small icon for this plugin in amongst your other toolbars and stuff at the top of your QGIS window. It is yellow like the normal selection icons. A side complaint I have is that it is never obvious where to find these installed plugins in QGIS and sometimes they are hard to find (as it is in this case).

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some hunting!