# Select overlapping features from single layer

Tags: qgis-3

in QGIS 3.10 LTR we have the opportunity to identify vector features with the mode "Top down".
Is there a way to do this with the "Select features"? We'd like to select all overlapping features when using the single click.

Comment: There was a plugin that can enable the user to [Select features from different vector layers at once?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/257557/63384), but unfortunately it is not compatible with QGIS 3.