# Selecting more than layer with polygon selection or select by location with different CRS in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, select

I want to select more than one layer in the same time, select by polygon not rectangle.

Comment: Create a polygon layer, draw your polygon, then use Select by location tool

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select features from different vector layers at once?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257474/select-features-from-different-vector-layers-at-once)

Comment: select by location should be in the same CRS . but in my situation i have different CRS. so it doesn't work. thanks for your concern.